# Define stress-strain for a multi-wall carbon nanotubes bundle

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, nanostructures, stress-strain

I want to simulate a MWCNT bundle in which the central MWCNT is pulled out of the bundle.
How to define the stress/strain curve of such system?

I am building my system with scikit-nano and using LAMMPS with Airebo-M force field for simulation.

1. create the geometry file:

```
from sknano.generators import MWNTBundleGenerator
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.visualize import view

mwntbundle = MWNTBundleGenerator(Nwalls=3, min_wall_diameter=5, Lz=5, bundle_geometry='hexagon')
mwntbundle.save('mwcnt_boundle.xyz')
mwcnt_ase = read('mwcnt_boundle.xyz')
view(mwcnt_ase)
```

2. Transform the so-produced xyz file into a lammps geometry file:

```
import numpy as np

def read_xyz(xyz_file):
    with open(xyz_file, 'r') as f:
        xyz_lines = f.readlines()
    n_atoms = int(xyz_lines[0])
    coords_str = np.array([ ll.split()[1:] for ll in xyz_lines[2:] ])
    coords_float = coords_str.astype(np.float)
    return n_atoms, coords_float

def write_lammps(coords):
    nat_per_mwcnt = len(coords)/7
    with open('mwcnt_boundle.lammps', "w+") as f:
        f.write('# LAMMPS data file \n\n')
        f.write(str(len(coords))+' atoms\n\n')
        f.write('1 atom types\n\n')
        f.write('-100 100 xlo xhi\n')
        f.write('-100 100 ylo yhi\n')
        f.write('-100 100 zlo zhi\n\n')
        f.write('Masses\n')
        f.write(' 1 12.010700 # C\n')
        f.write('Atoms\n')
        for cc in range(len(coords)):
            crd = coords[cc]
            ## creating 7 different molecules, each one corresponding to a MWCNT
            if cc%nat_per_mwcnt == 0:
                nmol = int(cc//nat_per_mwcnt)
            f.write( '{:4d} {:2d} 1 0 {:6f} {:6f} {:6f}\n'.format(cc+1, nmol, crd[0], crd[1], crd[2]) )
        f.write('\n')

n_atoms, coords = read_xyz("mwcnt_boundle.xyz")
write_lammps(coords)
```

3. At this point I can use LAMMPS to simulate the central mwcnt being pulled out of the bundle. The mwcnt correspond to residue 1. Please find below my input file. In a nutshell: I define a cilynder enclosing molecule G1 and pull it out with the displace_atoms command from LAMMPS. This will go into an external loop making it more effective.
   I have taken inspiration from [Ref1](https://lammpstutorials.github.io/tutorial04.html) and [Ref2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-perform-uniaxial-tensile-tests-graphene-sample-lammps-dewapriya/?trackingId=grfCMA6NR5aKzINRl0my7g%3D%3D).

I am defining the strain as the $\Delta$Z between the top layer of the shifted mwcnt and its initial position, while the stress is defined with "compute stress/atom".

Unsurprisingly, even with a larger system than the one produced here, I get a not very clear result, with strain/stress oscillating between -1e10 and 1e10.

Can anyone suggest a way to improve this simulation?
Thank you

Marco

```
# Initialisation

units           metal
dimension           3
boundary        p p p
atom_style      full 
newton          on

read_data       mwcnt_boundle.lammps 
pair_style      airebo/morse 3.0 1 1
pair_coeff      * * /data/mdi0316/WORK/MWCNT/src/Inputfiles/CH.airebo-m C

# time settings
variable        dt      equal   0.001
variable        tprod   equal   5
variable        Nruns    equal floor(${tprod}/${dt})
variable        Nevery   equal 10
variable        Nrepeat  equal 10
variable        Nfreq    equal 100
timestep        ${dt} #ps
print           "--- Time settings ---"
print           "    dt       = ${dt}"
print           "    tprod    = ${tprod}"
print           "    Nruns    = ${Nruns}"
print           "    Nevery   = ${Nevery}"
print           "    Nrepeat  = ${Nrepeat}"
print           "    Nfreq    = ${Nfreq}"

# computes and output variables settings
compute         cKe all ke
compute         cPe all pe
variable        totE equal c_cKe+c_cPe
compute         Tall all temp
compute         cP all pressure Tall
thermo          100
thermo_style    custom time temp pe v_totE press vol density

# ----------------------------------------------
# groups settings
group           G1 molecule 1
variable        xmax equal bound(G5,xmax)+0.5
variable        xmin equal bound(G5,xmin)-0.5
variable        zmax equal bound(G5,zmax)+0.5
variable        zmin equal bound(G5,zmin)-0.5
variable        Cdiam equal ${xmax}-${xmin}
variable        Cradi equal ${Cdiam}/2
variable        Cleng equal ${zmax}-${zmin}

variable        x_com_inner equal xcm(G1,x)
variable        y_com_inner equal xcm(G1,y)

region          innreg cylinder z ${x_com_inner} ${y_com_inner} ${Cradi} ${zmin} ${zmax}
variable        innvol equal ${Cleng}*3.14*${Cradi}*${Cradi}

#---------------STRESS-------------------------------------
compute         1 all stress/atom NULL
compute         2 all reduce sum c_1[3]
fix             1 all ave/time 1 1 100 c_2
variable        sigmazz equal f_1

## -------------- OUTPUTS ----------------------
fix             3 all ave/time 1 1 100 v_zmin v_zmax v_sigmazz file displace.dat

# ----------------------------------------------
# NPT

fix             bar all temp/berendsen 300 300 0.1 #Tstart Tstop Tdamp = 0.1ps
fix             mynpt all npt temp 300 300 0.1 aniso 1 1 1
dump            Dnpt all atom 100 dump_npt.lammpstrj
fix             fnpt all ave/time ${Nevery} ${Nrepeat} ${Nfreq} c_Tall v_totE c_cP v_innvol file npt.dat
print           "--- Beginning of NPT run (${Nruns} steps) ---"
#displace_atoms
displace_atoms  G1 move 0 0 10
run             ${Nruns}
write_data      restart.npt
undump          Dnpt
unfix           mynpt
unfix           fnpt

print           '---- DONE ----'
```

Comment: Hi Marco! I added the stress-strain tag, which not only can make your question more visible to possibly interested users, but will also bump your question up to the top of the site so that it's seen by more people again. Do you have any update for us since January? How is this project going?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is that these quantities are ill defined at the nanoscale and if there is some signal it would probably be seriously hidden by noise. 
Please check the discussion here: https://matsci.org/t/define-stress-strain-for-a-multi-wall-carbon-nanotubes-bundle/40183/2
Now I am now considering the longitudinal pressure on the nanotubes by calculating the geometrical area occupied by the carbon atoms on the xy plane. I also thought to define a 3D strain as the ratio of the volume under a gaussian fitted to the lower bound of the system, as a function of displacement.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reply because I didn't get pinged! You need to write @NikeDattani (for example) for your comment to show up in my notifications. I don't need to add the @ to ping you because the author of a question will always get pinged automatically! Have you been able to get an answer now? Please update us! It would be nice to get this question out of the unanswered queue since it's been almost 8 months!